# Alias "bootstrap.components.Bootstrap" is invalid

Tags: yii, yii-extensions

I've added bootstrap Extension To my yii webapp and installed as described in setup Guide. All Folders in Extension Folder are rwrwrw but i get the error written above. What could be the reason? I've already dumped the path from yii::Import and that path was correct.

Thanks!

**Edit With Code**

This is my config:

```
Yii::setPathOfAlias('bootstrap', dirname(__FILE__).'/../extensions/bootstrap');
//Yii::setPathOfAlias('bootstrap',     '/Users/gerritlober/Sites/yii/webapp/protected/extensions/bootstrap');

// This is the main Web application configuration. Any writable
// CWebApplication properties can be configured here.
return array(
'basePath'=>dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..',
'name'=>'My Carpool',
'theme' => 'bootstrap',

// preloading 'log' component
'preload'=>array('log'),

// autoloading model and component classes
'import'=>array(
    'application.models.*',
    'application.components.*',
),

'modules'=>array(
    // uncomment the following to enable the Gii tool
    'gii'=>array(
        'class'=>'system.gii.GiiModule',
        'password'=>'xxx',
        // If removed, Gii defaults to localhost only. Edit carefully to taste.
        'ipFilters'=>array('127.0.0.1','::1'),
        'generatorPaths'=>array(
            'bootstrap.gii',
        ),
    ),
),

// application components
'components'=>array(
    'user'=>array(
        // enable cookie-based authentication
        'allowAutoLogin'=>true,
    ),
    // uncomment the following to enable URLs in path-format

    'urlManager'=>array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'rules'=>array(
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        ),
    ),
    /*
    'db'=>array(
        'connectionString' => 'sqlite:'.dirname(__FILE__).'/../data/testdrive.db',
    ),*/
    // uncomment the following to use a MySQL database
    'db'=>array(
        'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=carpool_dev',
        'emulatePrepare' => true,
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'enableProfiling' => true,
    ),
    'authManager'=>array(
        'class'=>'CDbAuthManager',
        'connectionID'=>'db',
    ),
    'errorHandler'=>array(
        // use 'site/error' action to display errors
        'errorAction'=>'site/error',
    ),
    'log'=>array(
        'class'=>'CLogRouter',
        'routes'=>array(
            array(
                'class'=>'CFileLogRoute',
                'levels'=>'error, warning',
            ),
            // uncomment the following to show log messages on web pages
            array(
                'class'=>'CWebLogRoute',
                'categories' => 'system.db.*,GLWeb.*,application.*'
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'bootstrap'=>array(
        'class'=>'bootstrap.components.Bootstrap',
    ),
),

// application-level parameters that can be accessed
// using Yii::app()->params['paramName']
'params'=>array(
    // this is used in contact page
    'adminEmail'=>'webmaster@example.com',
),
```

);

My bootstrap extension is in ./protected/extensions/bootstrap

Comment: Please include your config/main.php code.

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem. I granted full(777) permission to the folder.

Try it.

Answer (score 2):

Update Component By :
`ext.bootstrap.src.components.Bootstrap'`,

EG: If you are extracted under extension then follow above command:

Syntax: `ext.path_to.Bootstrap`

Answer (score 0):

You have two options. One, in your `config/main.php` file, or equivalent, add the following line:

```
Yii::setPathOfAlias('bootstrap', dirname(__FILE__).'/../extensions/yii-bootstrap');
```

Where you need to replace `yii-bootstrap` with whatever your bootstrap folder is actually called.

Or two, you can simply refer to the that bootstrap folder correctly in the first place. If your bootstrap installation is installed in /extensions/yii-bootstrap as mine is, then use this alias to load components:

```
ext.yii-bootstrap.components.Bootstrap
```

In short, your problem is likely you aren't defining the path to your installation correctly. Use one of the two above solutions so remedy that problem.

Comment: Have you verified that within the bootstrap folder there is a folder named components, and within that a file named Bootstrap?